# High CPU LOAD on java.io.BufferedInputStream com.logica

Tags: java, multithreading, smpp

we have a java program which connects to a remote server over tcpip socket and sends async message and recieve response in a continuous while loop. there are 9 parallel threads running and extracting data from a single QUEUE.

Whenever no message is there is queue, then the program thread sleeps for 10 seconds and then query the queue again for message.  meanwhile, it is sending keepalive signal to the remote server also in every 10 seconds.

The program runs good for 1-2 days or more (with cpu utilization of 2-5 %) but after that the cpu utilization suddenly goes very high to 99-100% .If i kill and start it again,it works fine again.

I have taken the thread dump (using jstack) and also tried using visualvm.

Below is my thread dump.

```
2015-04-28 13:48:12
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.130.254.26" #60 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01069800 nid=0x1ffc runnable [0x164cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x0abb7bd8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:539)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0abb7d58> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.130.254.26" #59 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01067400 nid=0x1df8 runnable [0x15abf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x0a487300> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:539)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0a487480> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.130.254.26" #57 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01068800 nid=0x1714 runnable [0x152cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x0a2ba640> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:539)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0a2ba7c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"JMX server connection timeout 56" #56 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01068000 nid=0x1384 in Object.wait() [0x1532f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0a2a32c0> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    - locked <0x0a2a32c0> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01067800 nid=0xbcc waiting on condition [0x15b7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0a2819d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01066c00 nid=0xf20 runnable [0x15a4f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x0a27f8c8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-13" #51 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01066800 nid=0x13e0 runnable [0x156bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x0a00fd70> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-12" #50 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01066000 nid=0x11b0 runnable [0x1577f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x0a00d030> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-11" #49 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01065c00 nid=0x19a0 runnable [0x1563f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x09fca630> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-10" #48 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01065400 nid=0xde0 runnable [0x154ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x09fc63f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #45 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01064c00 nid=0x196c waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-36" #44 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01064800 nid=0x16f0 waiting on condition [0x1558f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-8" #41 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01064000 nid=0x114c runnable [0x150ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.available0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:155)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:485)
    - locked <0x096ac0b8> (a java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    - locked <0x096ab3f8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:426)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-32" #40 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01063c00 nid=0x1c60 waiting on condition [0x1538f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-7" #37 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01063400 nid=0x13e8 runnable [0x1521f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x0969d5e8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-28" #36 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01063000 nid=0x1a80 waiting on condition [0x1546f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-6" #33 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01062800 nid=0x1b6c runnable [0x153ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x0968e0d0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-24" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01062000 nid=0x1228 waiting on condition [0x1527f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-5" #29 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x146e6800 nid=0x12dc runnable [0x14ecf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x09685358> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-20" #28 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x146e0c00 nid=0x1054 waiting on condition [0x1515f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-16" #24 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0119f800 nid=0x195c waiting on condition [0x1501f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-3" #21 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01194400 nid=0xf2c runnable [0x14d7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x09666a28> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-12" #20 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01176800 nid=0x24c waiting on condition [0x14f4f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-2" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x14847c00 nid=0x17d0 runnable [0x14e3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x09637198> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:416)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-8" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x1483b400 nid=0x1904 waiting on condition [0x1508f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Receiver-1" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x1482c400 nid=0x1ebc runnable [0x14f9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.available0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:155)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:485)
    - locked <0x09640570> (a java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    - locked <0x09638800> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at com.logica.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:426)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:242)
    at com.logica.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:388)
    at com.logica.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:129)
    at com.logica.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-4" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x1482a800 nid=0x1cd8 waiting on condition [0x14ddf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.SendSms(SmsSend_Smpp.java:303)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsSend_Smpp.run(SmsSend_Smpp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-1" #9 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x147f7400 nid=0x1dc4 waiting on condition [0x14d0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MtsPreSms.SmsQueue.run(SmsQueue.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x01040400 nid=0x1068 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x01039000 nid=0xc94 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x01046c00 nid=0x1d9c waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x01045c00 nid=0x1cb0 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x01000800 nid=0x1ee8 in Object.wait() [0x03fdf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0956ed38> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x0956ed38> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x00ffb800 nid=0x1ce8 in Object.wait() [0x144cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0956eed8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x0956eed8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

kindly help me know you suggestions for improvement.

Comment: What about some code? How do you read from these sockets?

Comment: What did visualvm tell you?

Comment: Probably a "garbage collection" issue. Did you observe memory usage as well?

Comment: The calls to `available()` and `sleep()` are completely pointless. Just let your application block in `read().` That way the threads concerned will always block, once, for the correct length of time. So your throughout will improve and you don't run the risk of spin loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your server side getting Connection timeout. May be your client still waiting for response due to not sending any failure message.

`JMX server connection timeout 56" #56 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x01068000 com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)`